# Trying to write a assembly function that will insert a second string into a first string at a specific offset and return a pointer to the new string

Tags: c, assembly, arm

**My C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char * ins( char * string1, char * string2, int place ) ;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    char s1[] = "String to insert into" ;
    char s2[] = " this is the string to insert" ;
    int place = 9 ;
    char * result ;

    result = ins( s1, s2, place ) ;
    printf( "s1:\t%s\n", s1 ) ;
    printf( "s2:\t%s\n", s2 ) ;
    printf( "resulting string: %s\n", result ) ;

    exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

This C code will work with the following Assembly code as the function "ins" is defined below , The ARM compiler takes both C and assembly files and compiles them together...It should process the ins function in Assembly language , and print the result out from C.

---

**My Assembly Code:**

```
    .global ins
ins:
                stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} 
                mov v1, a1             
                bl strlen              
                add a1, a1, #1         
                mov v2, a1             
                bl malloc             
                mov v3, #0             
loop:           
                ldrb v4, [v1], #1       
                subs v2, v2, #1
                add v4, v4, a2         
                strb v4, [a1], #1                
                bne loop

                ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc} @std
.end
```

Comment: my code isn't compiling properly on ARM , can anyone please point my mistake or whatever i'm doing incorrect? THANKS

Comment: Saying `isn't compiling properly` isn't very informative - how did you compile it, what compiler are you using and what error do you get?

Comment: using the ARM compiler, which compiles both assembly and C code and prints the output.

Comment: its getting stuck in an infinite loop , in the assembly code i guess

Comment: How does it get stuck in an infinite loop if it doesn't compile? The whole question needs more specific details like the compiler command line, and perhaps the expected output - I'm not sure I've guessed correctly as to which interpretation of "insert" is correct in this context, but I'm _fairly_ sure it's not the "make a copy of the first string, but add some unknown value to every character (including the null terminator), and return a pointer past the end of it" one... Stepping through the instructions in a debugger and watching the data in the registers would be a _very_ valuable pastime.